# Server.Transfer to use alttemplate in umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have 2 templates for a single node. Based upon the user agent I am redirecting to the respective template using Response.Redirect("?alttemplate=template2").

I tried **Server.Transfer("/?alttemplate=template2",true);** but of no use.

Is it possible to do the same thing using Server.Transfer method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server.Transfer won't work with Umbraco (at least I've never got it to work). I believe this is to do with the fact that it doesn't fire all of the necessary Umbraco events to wire in the template correctly.

As Douglas states, you CAN use Response.Redirect though (and indeed you should, as you are changing the URL).

Another option is to wire into the page OnPreInit event, at which point you can change the the pages template using the MasterPageFile property of the page. This is assuming you are using the Asp.Net MasterPages templates, if you are using MVC Pages, I'm not sure how you'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Response.Redirect`, as `Server.Transfer` doesn't use the query string. See [server.Transfer with query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243054/server-transfer-with-query-string) and [Query string in Server.Transfer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1068832.aspx).

For more information, see See [Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect).