# Set the value of an unbound DropDownList based on values passed in a querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set the value of an unbound `DropDownList` based on values passed in a query string without success.

I don't have error but in `DropDownList` the value passed in a query string is not selected.

Here is my code.

**In `page1.aspx`**:

```
Server.Transfer("page2.aspx?dt=" + myDateDDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

**In `page2.aspx`**:

```
Server.Transfer("page1.aspx?dt=" + Request.QueryString["dt"].ToString());
```

**In `page1.aspx`**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["dt"]))
       {
           myDateDDL.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["dt"].ToString();
       }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all you can't pass query string with `Server.Transfer`. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1243062/1529657. Secondly you are passing `selected text` and trying to set `selected value` so it will never work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass value in query string using `Server.Transfer`.

Use **Response.Redirect()** to pass query string it will solve your issue.

Example

```
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx?dt=" + myDateDDL.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

[Differences between Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/724972/Difference-Between-Response-Redirect-and-Server-Tr)